# Android SDK: how to read a USB device's class?

Tags: android, usb

I have tried writing primitive activity for scanning USB port and displaying basic info for attached device. I am specifically interested in reading device class, which I believe [UsbDevice.getDeviceClass ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDevice.html#getDeviceClass%28%29) method is intended for. Here's what it looks like:

```
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = findUsbDevices();
    Iterator<UsbDevice> deviceIterator = deviceList.values().iterator();
    if (deviceIterator.hasNext())
    {
        UsbDevice device = deviceIterator.next();
        String name = device.toString();
        String cls = Integer.toString(device.getDeviceClass());
        displayDeviceInfo(name, cls);
    }
```

However, it doesn't work as expected, giving 0 for any device I connect. Many other fields of UsbDevice object, like subclass or protocol, are also 0. How can I get device class then?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USB class is the attribute of interface, not device. Iterating interfaces works as expected:

```
int count = device.getInterfaceCount();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
{
    UsbInterface iface = device.getInterface(i);
    int cls = iface.getInterfaceClass();
}
```